# Assembly Number Guessing Game

Tags: assembly, random, x86, masm32

I'm trying to make a number guessing game in assembly code that starts out with a range of 1 to 1, then increments by 1 each time you get the answer right.

For some reason though when I run the program the number that is output for range is incredibly high instead of 1, and when I type in 1 which is the answer for the first round it says I lose instead of continuing. So if anyone could help me with those problems that would be great!

```
 include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

.data

formatString BYTE  "guess a number from 1 to %d , if you get it right you continue", 0ah, 0dh, 0 
guessstr BYTE  11 DUP (0)
guess DWORD ?
range DWORD 0
answer DWORD 1
prompt BYTE  "You lose!", 0

.code
main proc
    call seedrand

nextlevel:
    move eax, 0
    mov range, ebx
    add ebx, 1
    pushd ecx
    call randnum
    invoke crt_printf, ADDR formatString, ebx
    invoke StdIn, ADDR guessstr, 10
    invoke atodw, ADDR guessstr
    mov guess, edx
    add ecx, 1

    cmp eax, ebx
    je nextlevel

    invoke StdOut, ADDR prompt
    jnz skip

seedrand proc
    ; seeds the random number generator
    ; _stdcall
    invoke GetTickCount ; result goes in eax
    invoke nseed, eax

    ret
seedrand endp

randomnum proc
    ; generate a random number
    ; _stdcall
    mov eax, [esp+4]
    invoke nrandom, eax

    ret 4
randomnum endp


skip:

    ; return 0
    mov eax, 0
    ret

main endp
end main
```

Comment: These all sounds like good plans. Unfortunately, you have failed to actually ask a question.

Comment: I edited it, i guess i mentioned the problems, but didn't actually ask for help with them

Comment: So what do you see when you single-step in a debugger?  At what point is there a taken branch that you expected not to be taken, or a register with a value that isn't what you expected?  Learning to use a debugger for asm is absolutely essential.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> move eax, 0
> ```

This is not a valid instruction. Could it be that you meant to initialize the upper limit? Because that's something you forgot! Replace it by `xor ebx, ebx`

> ```
> cmp eax, ebx
> je nextlevel
> ```

You just moved the user's guess from the `EDX` register to the *guess* variable. Here you should be comparing with one of these, certainly not with the upper limit.

> ```
> invoke StdOut, ADDR prompt
> jnz skip
> ;
> seedrand proc
> ```

After displaying "You lose!" you fall through in the *seedrand* procedure. Better use `jmp skip`.